# Dictionary Inconsistent Accesability

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, public

I get an error in the code below on the first mention of the word tables. I need that dictionary to be usable by all classes.

the error reads:

> Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' is less accessible than field 'RiskRatingReevaluation.RiskRatingLogic.tables'   C:\Users\jholland\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RiskRatingReevaluation\RiskRatingReevaluation\RiskRatingLogic.cs    13  49  RiskRatingReevaluation

```
public static class RiskRatingLogic
{

    public static Dictionary<string, Table> tables;

    public static void Main()
    {

        tables = new Dictionary<string, Table>();
        ImportRegionIndexes(tables);
```

Any suggestions of what to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your Table class is not `public`. The error is exactly as it sounds, one class is less accessible (public, internal, private, protected) than the one calling it

Take a look at [the accessibility levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

Comment: I changed that but was still getting the error. turns out that I had to clean the solution to make the error disapear

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Justin Pihony
Changing the class access modifier should solve the problem.
I too was facing the same problem.